# Switch between Screens/Activities without a button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, screen

I need some help. With  my rudimentary java knowlengde I have found out, how to switch between Activities really easy, but I am stuck in a question:
How can I do this without a view or a button in an if Statement.

So I need following:

```
if(everythingisfine) {changeScreen(nextScreen)}
```

I already tried it with:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frage.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

but it didn't work. The App stopped. I can't give you a bug-report, because I can only test it on my device (it is using GPS).

Comment: Is Frage registered as an activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes it is :] `<activity android:name="com.example.romrallye.Frage"></activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Frage.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

where `this` is reference to current activity.

Comment: `The constructor Intent(Rally.MyLocationListener, Class<Frage>) is undefined`
:/

Comment: Put there reference of your activity. NameOfTheClass.this

Answer (score -1):

I think to achieve your goal, you can just use different layout files (`<layoutname>.xml`) and then you can switch the layout if everything is fine by just doing `setContentView(R.layout.<layoutname>)` inside your activiy.

Of course, you could use different activities but it is not necessarily needed and especially if you have a smaller app, it's enough to just switch layouts. But if you do so, you have to watch out for NullPointerException's because if you are doing `findViewById()` and you supply an id of a view on a different layout than the current, you will get `null` back and then receive the NPE when trying to access the view.

Comment: Do NOT do this. I don't understand why would anyone even suggest doing this. This is not only bad design, but also overly complicates your current activity and is a source of numerous bugs that will waste hours of your time. Also it is a hell for memory. It will make your activity hold the references for the objects used in the previous screens and will grow the memory usage rapidly. What is wrong with just using activities?

Comment: You are completely right when talking about it being bad design, but sometimes - really only **sometimes** - it is good for **really small** apps.

Comment: If the activity is the .java File I need to switch it. :/
Because I use an GPS-Script that crashes, if I try to get an other Button in it :]